# How can I send an email if there are any change in fieldname values (example email, stats of task) by checking from existing database

Tags: emails

I need your help or suggestions in create custom module where I need send an email to user and admin if there is any status change in ticket or field values changes (such as description updated) in existing database.

- **Things I know:**
  drupal_mail() function helps me to send email and HOOK_mail() helps me to format the mail structure and I need to implement these in '<module_name>.module' file.

But,i need your suggestions in implementation for checking the data values of specific field(such as description field). if values are change, mail need to trigged.

I am open for any suggestions. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to know what has been changed when an entity is updated. You can do that using [hook_entity_update()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_update) or [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update):

> This hook runs once the entity storage has been updated. Note that hook implementations may not alter the stored entity data. Get the original entity object from $entity->original.

For instance, assuming you want to know whether the `field_description` has been changed when a node gets updated, you can do that in your `.module` file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update() for node entities.
 */
function <module-name>_node_update(NodeInterface $node) {
  if ($node->get('field_description')->value !== $node->original->get('field_description')->value) {
    // Apply the logic when the description field changes.
  }
}
```

where `<module-name>` is the name of your module.

Comment: Worked... thank you